# Is there a fancier Console library for C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any library for .NET which can:

- output characters/words in color
- draw stuff in console like progress bars (similar to wget)
- other funny beautiful things i might consider using in my glamor console app

Comment: glamour console app...love it haha

Comment: There are use cases for it, especially since .NET does not mean Windows.

Comment: Check: [Console library](http://www.retroginger.com/code-area/c/console-library/)

Comment: closed in 4 years since the original post ))

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes; the [`Console` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) can do all of that.

- Set [`Console.ForegroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx)
- Print [Unicode Box Drawing Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_characters) and set `CursorLeft` and `CursorTop`
- Such as?

Comment: Sounds interesting... care to elaborate?

Comment: Good answer, but would be more useful with some helper lib as it was originally asked - i.e. `box.Draw(startPoint, endPoint, backgroundColor, lineStyle, ...)`

Answer (score 23):

## ConsoleEx

The [ConsoleEx](https://github.com/AnthonyMastrean/ConsoleEx) library, written a long time ago by Microsoftie, [Tim Sneath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/), can do some advanced coloring and writing to positions. It's generally a lot better than the Console, even the .NET 4.0 Console (as far as I can tell).

And it's on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/ConsoleEx)!

Comment: I don't see anything there that `Console` doesn't have, except for the `DrawRectangle` wrapper.

Comment: The API seems nicer. WriteAt doesn't move the cursor after write. I think if someone could do a real side-by-side comparison, with _working_ code, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a bit of success with a progress indicator. This block is called from an event and may be called from multiple threads. it displays 1% and increments as appropriate on one line.

```
private object thislock = new Object();
void UpdateProgress(DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (thislock)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\b");
        }
        Console.Write(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    }
}
```