# Console Application to update certain values and not scroll

Tags: c#, .net, console

I would like to write a .NET Console Application that shows certain values and statistics.

For this I need the Console to not scroll and write to certain places on the console window.

I have seen this behaviour in other applications as well (e.g. unix top/htop) and was wondering if there is a libary for .NET to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Console.SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.console.setcursorposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to position the cursor over existing text so you overwrite it instead of "appending" to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823066/is-there-a-fancier-console-library-for-c) for possibilities.

The built-in `Console` class also has `CursorLeft`, `CursorTop`, `WindowWidth`, and `WindowHeight` properties that you can use to figure out the size of the console window, and `SetCursorPosition` to position the cursor prior to writing. The documentation for the [Console Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) might give you a hint for any other functionality you need.